# IndexedDb - how do I access it?

Tags: indexeddb

I have an application that runs on my mac.  This application appears to write to a folder labeled labeled IndexedDB.  Inside that folder there are 4 files without an extension and 1 log file.

Is there a software that can be used to visualize the data of an Indexed Database? I know some SQL but I'm not sure this will be helpful here as I understood that database structure is different.

Essentially, I want to browse the data and see its content and to see how the data is organized.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the contents of indexedDB using the browser devtools. In Chrome, on the Applications tab of devtools, you can click on indexedDb and then browse the contents of the object stores.

SQL is of no use to you here. indexedDB is a nosql database.

How indexedDB is actually implemented, in terms of where and how it actually stores data on your computer's hard drive, is intentionally obfuscated. indexedDB data is not intended to be accessed in this manner. indexedDB data is only intended to be accessed using the indexedDB API in javascript in the browser.

Comment: Sorry, not exactly an expert, but could you give me instructions on how to do that?  I opened Chrome --> View --> Developer --> Developer Tools.   Now what?  how do I paste the folder path?  The folder path is:  

~/Library/Application Support/myApplication/IndexedDB/

Comment: You are not browsing a folder or a file. How data is saved on your hard drive by the browser is intentionally obfuscated. In  dev tools, visit the Applications tab, and look for the indexedDB section in the left menu of this tab. Click on the section name, expand it, examine the databses.  Clicking on a store will show the contents of the store in the adjacent panel.

Comment: Thanks.  But it's blank.  I open a blank page in chrome, and "IndexDb" under "Storage" is empty.  If I click on "Clear Storage" under "Application" section, I get the following:

0 B used out of 641509 MB storage quota

Comment: clearing storage deletes the data, and you can only see databases created under the "origin" of the website you are browsing, the origin is basically the domain part of the url like "www.stackoverflow.com". If I am not on stackoverflow.com, I cannot see the indexedDB databases created by stackoverflow.com

Comment: right, but I'm trying to see the indexedDb located in a folder on my local machine - not on a web site.  Is there a way to do that?  if so how?

Thanks again.

Comment: you're asking about intentionally obfuscated information, each browser makes its own decisions here and it uses different files to store the data, and you cannot simply edit these files or copy in your own, that is not how things work

Comment: I probably did not explain myself well.  Let me take another stab at it.  So I installed an application on my local machine.  As I'm running this application, it writes to a folder on my local machine.  I browsed to that folder and found out that its name is indexedDb.  It has a bunch of files without extensions.  I'm interested in what is being written in these files.  Is there a way to view the structure/data in these files (or this indexedDb)?  If the answer is yes, how?
Thanks.

Comment: can you write custom javascript in the app anywhere? otherwise, you are entirely on your own because you are trying to access raw data files that are not intended for access

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot.  Thanks for your help.